# Sveltekit: Issue with refresh using store and localStorage

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to persist data using localStorage. The persistence is working. When I refresh I get the initial value of 0 and then it gets the localStorage value. Is there a way for me to get localStorage value instant without showing 0. Or is it impossible.

My store code:

```
import { clickPower } from "$lib/store";
import { browser } from "$app/environment";

/** This is the highest total the kebab count has reached **/
export function createHighest() {
    const { subscribe, set } = writable(0);

    return {
        subscribe,
        set: (value: number) => set(value),
        reset: () => set(0),
    };
}

/** **/
export function createTotal() {
    const localTotal = browser && localStorage.getItem("totalKebabs");
    const totalStore = writable(localTotal ? parseInt(localTotal) : 0);
    const { subscribe, set, update } = totalStore;

    return {
        subscribe,
                 // My functions go here
        ....
    };
}
```

And the code to display it:

```
    {#key $totalKebabs}
        <span>{$totalKebabs}</span>
        Kebabs
    {/key}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you turn off [server-side rendering](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr), there will always be a mismatch between what the server initially sends and what is then read from storage on the page.

The only other workaround I can think of, would be to make the store asynchronous so it has to be awaited. But this is far from great as the usage ergonomics are bad and you still will get a visible delayed update on the page.

Of course, you could choose to store the information elsewhere entirely, so it would be accessible to the server and thus during SSR.